# Expressions call constructor with a parameter and set its value

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, lambda, expression-trees

i am trying to call an parameterized constructor from an expression instead of using the default ctor. this is the code that gets the constructor parameter(s):

```
ConstructorInfo ci = type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, CallingConventions.HasThis, new[] { typeof(bool) }, new ParameterModifier[] { });
ParameterInfo[] paramsInfo = ci.GetParameters();

//create a single param of type object[]
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(bool), "il");

Expression[] argsExp = new Expression[paramsInfo.Length];

//pick each arg from the params array 
//and create a typed expression of them
for (int i = 0; i < paramsInfo.Length; i++)
{
    Expression index = Expression.Constant(i);
    Type paramType = paramsInfo[i].ParameterType;

    Expression paramAccessorExp = param;
    //Expression.ArrayIndex(param, index);

    Expression paramCastExp =
        Expression.Convert(paramAccessorExp, paramType);

    argsExp[i] = param;
}                  

NewExpression ci2 = Expression.New(ci, argsExp);
```

But if i try to compile the lambda expression i am getting the following error:

> variable 'il' of type 'System.Boolean' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

What am i missing? Any help and/ or hint is appreciated.

Comment: thank you both, i will try your suggestions tomorrow an let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a parameter called `li` in the 4th line of your code. In order to use this in a lambda expression, you need to have a scope in which this parameter is defined. You have two choices:

1. Create a `BlockExpression` that contains `param` as a local variable. Then use this expression as the body of your lambda expression.
2. Use `param` as a parameter in your `LambdaExpression`.

If you use option 1, you'll also have to initialize the variable. Otherwise you'll get a different kind of error message.

**EDIT**

There are two problems with the additional code you posted:

1. You need to use the same parameter object throughout your expression tree. Having the same name  and type does not make two `Parameter` objects equal. I would simply move everything up to and including creating the lambda to the `ConvertThis` method so you can reuse the `param` variable. You can then just compile the return value of `ConvertThis` to get your delegate.
2. When creating the `BlockExpression`, you need to pass `param` in as a local variable. You do this by adding an argument, `new ParameterExpression[] { param }` to the method.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, i'm trying your suggestion, but still have no idea. Please see my additions above.